# how to get Binary (1010) of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, data-conversion

I need to get pure binary of a file. From pure binary I mean

```
1010101010
```

I have tried this:

```
with open('img.jpg', 'rb') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

This gives me the below output:

```
d2$I\xa7\xf3\x196\x8d\xc8\x9cmS\xc7Z{L\xd8r\x89\x85\x1f\xf2\xd3\x07\x8fjd\x90\xa6P\x03\xb0\x1e\xb5,n\xb0\xafo~\xf4\x
```

I do not need this, because I am working with binary of a file. Instead I need

```
101011110101010110101000000001010101011111010000011010010101
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I need this because I am working to compress the data i mean 1,0 so first I need to see the 1,0 , I have made algo which is working fine for me now i need a real file 1,0 not generated 1,0

Comment: Just work with the bytes. You can use bitwise operators rather than inefficient string literals (which will likely make your data explode in size by a factor of 16 or so) if you want access to the individual bits in the bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('img.jpg', 'rb') as file:
    print("".join(bin(b)[2:] for b in file.read()))
```

Why you would need this is beyond me, since computers work in `1`s and `0`s, not `"1"`s and `"0"`s, and usually when representing binaries to humans you'd use `oct`al or `hex`idecimal.

Comment: Sir I need 1010 because I am working on data compression & I need 1,0 for computer not for human.

Comment: @ShahidKhan Run length encoding? Ok, but keep in mind that in the "real world" it won't be done quite like this.

Answer (score 0):

So, that's actually the same thing. A character of the form `\xa7` is something that is understood by file readers to mean `10100111`.

```
>>> bin(ord('\xa7')) # => 167
```

If you want the binary representation, specifically as `0`s and `1`s, you can use something similar to what I've used above to get it, but any program expecting binary should work with actual binary characters, which will look like `\xa7` or something else when printed on the screen via python.